# Setting axis range

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to set the matplotlib axis range. Here's what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[0.06951477907468373, 0.7103500283126181, 2.2594683649406164, 6.232291833949004, 15.0], [0.07037210864897858, 0.6882762072247406, 2.139571761631302, 5.648686905562515, 15.0], [0.07123329426356406, 0.6674632711418962, 2.026660485523852, 5.069905770669195, 15.0], [0.07209824436252887, 0.6478499470578196, 1.9038606544459693, 4.518228163857106, 10.573194995337474], [0.07296686668366092, 0.6293755546338424, 1.7851817546524789, 4.015067334043049, 7.689027613108544]]

# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
plot = plt.pcolormesh(data,
               cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('Greys_r'))

plot.set_clim(vmin=0, vmax=20)

plt.colorbar(fraction=0.045)
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')

plt.show()
```

which results in:

[image]

But I am trying to get:

[image]

Comment: You will probably have to manually adjust the ticks of both axes to be in the middle of the pixel (by adding 0.5), and then setting the tick labels to your desired ones